# Assign IAM role depending on cognito user-sub (userId) using IAM Condition

Tags: amazon-iam, amazon-cognito

I have a hard time assigning an IAM role to a user depending on the cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub Key using the Condition element.

When setting up the identity-pool using AWS Cognito you can specify an «Authenticated role» where i selected the *app-authenticated* role.

I have two IAM Roles:

**app-authenticated**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "eu-central-1:fa078075-9622-4f0d-8789-700105a9e612"
        },
        "StringNotEquals": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub": "eu-central-1:555540a6-cd49-44b2-bbd8-02cfa73b3510"
        },
        "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "authenticated"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and

**app-authenticated_admin**

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Federated": "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:aud": "eu-central-1:fa078075-9622-4f0d-8789-700105a9e612",
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub": "eu-central-1:555540a6-cd49-44b2-bbd8-02cfa73b3510"
        },
        "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
          "cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:amr": "authenticated"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The Problem is that whoever loggs in, he always gets the *app-authenticated* role, also the one user with the sub «555540a6-cd49-44b2-bbd8-02cfa73b3510» (copied from userPool -> users -> user detail -> sub) which I would expect to get the *app-authenticated_admin* role. Is anyone expecting something similar, or am I missing some basic concepts for such a simple scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Deny` instead of `Allow` in unauthenticated users.
Also have you tried user groups in user pools.

Comment: Thanks for pushing me into the right direction. I ended up using the new group feature (important: don't forget to define «Choose from token» in the «Authentication Providers» section of the federated identities management console where you link your cognito user pool. No additional configuration in IAM required.